# When to LOCK TABLES in MySQL (MyISAM tables)?

Tags: mysql, concurrency, locking, myisam

Is the [internal locking of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html) sufficient for a small to medium sized website? My tables are MyISAM. There might be a few hundred people concurrently hitting a specific table with SELECT'S and INSERT's. None of the INSERT/UPDATE queries would overlap. That is, no two users will be updating the same comment ID. INSERT's/UPDATE's would be one-off operations---there would be no reading of data and performing additional operations within the same query.

Specifically, I am setting up a comment/chat system for my website. At worst, there might be a couple of hundred people performing a SELECT statement on the comment/chat tables in order to read new posts. With respect to INSERT's, there might be 100(?) different people trying to INSERT a new comment at any time.

I found [this article](http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/php/php_mysql/When_and_how_to_lock_tables.html) in another question on SO, and it states that LOCK TABLES is "never required for self-contained insert, update, or delete operations." Is this good practice for the amount of DB traffic that I might have? TIA for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only form of locking MyISAM tables is table locks. The idea is that they designed it to be way-fast enough that no one else should need access while it works. Right - YMM definitely V. But for most small-to-medium-size websites, it's fine. For intance, that's what WordPress uses.

Comment: Would it be better to implement some form of locking now---anticipating a larger user audience? It's my understanding that MyISAM tables allow for concurrent queries (INSERT/UPDATE/SELECT/etc.), and that there is a MySQL system variable that handles those concurrent events ( [concurrent_insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_concurrent_insert) ). This variable deals with the way MyISAM tables handle holes (from DELETES/etc.) in the middle of tables. Can these "holes" be a source of data corruption if not handled properly? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Locking is probably only something you need to worry about if rows are being viewed *and edited* at the same time.  Don't worry about locking for what you're doing - it's not only good practice to do so, using locks here would hurt performance.